# Unusual Background Issue when using Bootstrap theme - ASP.NET Core

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, background, asp.net-core

I have a html page using a bootstrap theme. I have a slight problem with CSS styling. It is a problem I have never come across. The problem is that the background doesn't fill the page on page load, only when the page is resized dos it fill the page. Any suggestions?

Thanks,

James Hyland

Here is the _Layout.cshtml code;

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <style>

        #side-navbar-footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            display: block;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 1.42857143;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
        }

        .dropdown-toggle{
            color:black;
        }

        #page-wrapper {
            background: radial-gradient(white 10%, grey );
            background-size: cover;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>HBL Website</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav id="navbar-top" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Hylands Biggest Loser</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Login</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->
            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                        <li class="sidebar-search">
                            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i>   My Progress<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Weights</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Target Weight</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">My Summary</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>  My Group<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Members</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Summary</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a style="bottom:0" href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> Needlecast Ltd. 2017</a>
                        </li>

                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">


                        @RenderBody()


                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Layout", required: false);
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)


    <environment names="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>


</body>

</html>
```

And here is the Index.cshtml code (which isnt causing the issue);

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";
}

<style>
    *{
        text-align:center;

    }

</style>
<body >
    <img src="~/img/asset 1.jpg"/>

    <h1>Welcome to Hylands Biggest Loser!</h1>
    <h2>Click the buttons on the side. They will allow you to view your weights, progress, and your overall weekly summary.</h2>
    <h2>You can also view the other members in your group, as well as a weekly summary for all members.</h2>
</body>
```

Comment: yes please share the code needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: How big is your image, might be a factor?

Comment: The background isn't an image, it is the main .body element which is having a problem

Comment: Does it help if you add this style? `html, body, #page-wrapper { height: 100%; }`

Comment: let me check that

Comment: Why does your `Index.cshtml` have a `body`? You can only have 1 `body` and that is defined on your `Layout.cshtml`

Comment: no it doesn't help the background is still cut off

Comment: try adding `#wrapper` to that style also

Comment: @JamesHyland that code doesn't reproduce any sort of problem for me. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LymZJV please reproduce the problem for us with a demo. see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: that's because to reproduce it you would need the whole solution :)

Comment: well, most of it anyway :)

Comment: Did you try this? `html, body, #wrapper, #page-wrapper { height: 100%; }`

Comment: @JamesHyland, you could just view source and copy that into a fiddle with the styles, rather than showing us your razor, it would be more useful to see the rendered html and the styles that affect it.  But I would remove the body tags from your index.cshtml and then move that style into an external style sheet - it is only valid for style tags to be in the body if they have the scoped attribute - all the content of that index.cshtml file will appear where your `RenderBody()` is in your _Layout.cshtml

Comment: @zgood please put this as an answer so I can mark it as correct. This worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set all your main wrapper elements to have a height of 100% and your background should always take up at least 100% of the page.

Add this css style:

`html, body, #wrapper, #page-wrapper { height: 100%; }`